# I would like to share sharing permissions for the list view function by profile

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, list-view, sharing-rule

I want to set sharing permissions for the list view function for each profile.

Is there a way to disable certain “A” profile user groups from using the “all users can see this view” feature and only use the “share list view groups of users” “only me view” feature?

Answer (score 0):

No. There's a single permission on the profile called Manage Public List Views.  A user with this permission can use all three options, and those without can only use the Only Me option.